# multiple choice quiz using Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter-3

i have two tables for this project. The Questions Table and The Answers Table.
And i want the question_id feild value in the Questions Table to be the same for every options inserted inserted into Answers table with another field name question_id

But each time i did that, i got these results:

[Questions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvECu.png)

[Answers Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGpNA.png)

As u can see the question_ids are not the same and thats not what i want.

Here is my code:
public function insert_correct_ans($answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4)
    {

$id = $this->db->insert_id();

```
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO answers(
                                            question_id, 
                                            answer, 
                                            correct) 
                                   VALUES(
                                   '$lastID',
                                   '$answer1', '1')");

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO answers(
                                            question_id, 
                                            answer, 
                                            correct) 
                                   VALUES(
                                   '$lastID',
                                   '$answer2', '0')");

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO 
                                    answers(
                                            question_id, 
                                            answer, 
                                            correct) 
                                   VALUES(
                                        '$lastID',
                                        '$answer3', '0')");

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO 
                                    answers(
                                            question_id, 
                                            answer, 
                                            correct)
                                   VALUES(
                                   '$lastID',
                                   '$answer4', '0')");
}
```

Comment: what is the value `$lastID`. And how you got its value.

Comment: You also have to send the question id on this function.

Comment: i asigned $lastID the value of $this->db->insert_id()

Comment: don't know if that's the right way to do it

Comment: did u `echo $lastID;`.What is output.

Comment: ok wait i will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of calling to the function `insert_correct_ans()` also pass the question id.So and then copy the following code.Rather data writing insert query repeatedly make the array and user CI database insert function.

```
              <?php
      public function insert_correct_ans($que_id,$answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4)
           {
            $data=array(
              array(
                'question_id'=>$que_id,
                'answer'=>$answer1,
                'correct'=>'1'
                ),
              array(
                'question_id'=>$que_id,
                'answer'=>$answer2,
                'correct'=>'0'
                ),
              array(
                'question_id'=>$que_id,
                'answer'=>$answer3,
                'correct'=>'0'
                ),
             array(
                'question_id'=>$que_id,
                'answer'=>$answer4,
                'correct'=>'0'
                )
              );
            }
            $this->db->insert('answers',$data);
          ?>
```

Comment: could that mean i would have to input the question id myself?

Comment: Ok, lemme give it a try... I'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: I have edited the code which is more understandable and clear lets enjoy..

Comment: I have edited the code which is more understandable and clear lets enjoy..

Comment: That looks great, but one thing is still confusing, i want get the question id from the Questions table

Comment: For this, when you are going to set the answers...Just select the que_id.from database.

Comment: Here you are going to set the answer of the question manually..so just set question_id as above.